# How to add iframe of rocket chat in website

Tags: iframe, rocket.chat

As i have read rocket chat documentation for i frame automatically login i follow these steps

1. Go to Adminstration > Accounts > Iframe and enable it.
2. Hit rest api and got userId and authToken .
   But from where i got iframe code and how can i integrate it with application

Meteor.loginWithToken('3wzsXzG53AN5qU_byQVZZNt79oh5wviOMpwB2IHOyHR', callback);
I got this error :
Uncaught ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined

And where i used rocket server url . Please help me how can i login in rocket chat automatically when login in our application using iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use IframeId with meteor call as below

document.getElementById(iframeId).Meteor.loginWithToken('3wzsXzG53AN5qU_byQVZZNt79oh5wviOMpwB2IHOyHR');